# jQuery (events and layout) not working in PhoneGap (Android) app

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

The events (transition, click, load, alert) of my app (jQuery Mobile) **works on browser, but not when I build it for Android using PhoneGap.**

- Note 1. In the browser, I click, and it redirects to a page, shows alerts, draw all the layout, views, ... But in the emulator nothing works.
- Note 2. I think the most important is doing the right reference to scripts. But since it works on Browsers, I supposed it's good.

---

This is how it looks on browsers:

[image]

---

This is how it looks on the emulator:

[image]

---

This is my directory:

[image]

---

And here is the code:
**/www/index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>tittle</title>
   <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
   <script>
     window.location='app/index.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**/www/app/index.html:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="login-page" >
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <form id="check-user" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">
                <fieldset>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="user_email">Enter your username:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="user_email" id="user_email"/>
                    </div>                                 
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                     
                        <label for="user_password">Enter your password:</label>
                        <input type="password" value="" name="user_password" id="user_password"/>
                    </div>
                    <a href=""  >
                    <input type="button"  name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></a>
                </fieldset>
            </form>             
    </div>
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

**/www/app/js/global.js:**

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#login-page', function(){ 
        $(document).on('vclick', '#submit', function() {
        alert(' Hi......!');
  });
```

Comment: It is difficult to determine what you're asking. Perhaps you could restate the question more concisely, with an example of something you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: @harbichidian I have tried moving the files, changing the links, changing the events, ... But the problem is with PhoneGap, since it works on browsers

Comment: *What* is the problem?

Comment: @harbichidian Well, please take a look at the images, the jQuery layout doesn't work, neither the events (alert, as shown in the code). Thanks.

Comment: where are your jquery libraries? document ready? where you have included it? outside index.html?